# Como passar um Array para a cláusula IN de uma query plana?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, orm, active-record

Estou utilizando o ActiveRecord para executar queries em vários bancos de dados diferentes. Em uma das consultas, eu tenho de fazer o seguinte:

```
publications_to_read = [1,2,3,4]
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("ALTER TABLE publications SET readed = TRUE WHERE id IN (#{publications_to_read});")
```

Se eu estivesse fazendo isso a partir de uma classe que herdasse de `ActiveRecord::Base`, haveria uma forma bem mais intuitiva de fazer isso, mas não é o caso.

O que eu preciso é de interpolar este array na query de modo que o resultado final seja assim:

```
publications_to_read = [1,2,3,4]
# Query usando o array adaptado
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("ALTER TABLE publications SET readed = TRUE WHERE id IN ('1', '2', '3', '4');")
```

Alguém sabe me dizer como eu poderia alcançar esse resultado? Eu já tentei fazer algo como `publications_to_read.join(',')` mas não deu certo. O array é convertido em uma única String e dá erro.

Answer (score 0):

Tentou fazer de uma maneira que o resultado final fique exatamente "`'1','2','3','4'`"?

Tente usar o join assim: `\'#{publications_to_read.join('\',\'')}\'`.

Answer (score 0):

Você não está utilizando o ActiveRecord. Você está enviando comandos SQL em uma conexão direta ao BD.
Se você quer usar a abstração que o ActiveRecord provê:

```
class Publication < ActiveRecord::Base 
end

Publication.find([1,2,3,4]).update_all(readed: true) #=>sem callbacks ou validations, em um único commando SQL

Publication.find([1,2,3,4]).each {|pub| pub.update(readed: true)} #=>com callbacks e validations, comandos SQL individuais
```